# Gremlin : How to get all the vertex details in the traversal?

Tags: gremlin, gremlin-server, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

Sample Data

```
A knows B
A knows C
A knows D
B knows E
C knows F
```

Desired Output

```
B
C
D
E
F
```

I tried the following query, but it's not working,

```
g.V('A').
out('knows').
as('x').
out('knows').
as('x').
project('Employee').
by(select('x'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get all the vertices in the path you can do:

```
g.V('A').repeat(out("knows")).emit().label()
```

example: https://gremlify.com/c533ij58a98z8

Comment: Is it possible to add a projection after?

Comment: @KajalPatel after the `g.V('A').repeat(out("knows")).emit()` you can do whatever you need. you have all the vertices, I added the `label` step just because of your desire output

Comment: I did try that, but I am getting this error, **The provided traversal or property name of path() does not map to a value.**

Comment: what did you try? If you using `project` make sure all your `by` steps are mapping to a value. if you need help extend the gremlify example and send it here.

Comment: I got that. But can you help with something, suppose want to project a constant with B,C,D and a different constant with E,F. Is this possible? Basically, differentiate the output based on what level it was found.

Comment: @KajalPatel You can add `sack` for depth: https://gremlify.com/c777wa0c9lsvx

Comment: I think that's not supported in Cosmos DB Gremlin API, is there an alternative?